# Error al denifinir mensajes

Tags: php, html, jquery

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]buenas tardes tengo un codigo php para registrar el usuario y validar la activacion por medio del correo electronico, pero al dar en el correo activar registro me sale un mensaje de error de que mi variable mensaje no ha sido definida y no me actualiza el registro de la base de datos. si alguien tuviese una idea de como solucionarlo me seria de mucha ayuda.
adjunto a la pregunta esta el codigo de validacion, el de activacion y el del link de envio de registro, si me almacena el usuario mas no me actualiza el estado para la activacion del mismo.

```js
function validaIdToken($id, $token){
  global $mysqli;
  
  $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT activacion FROM usuarios WHERE id = ? AND token = ? LIMIT 1");
  $stmt->bind_param("is", $id, $token);
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->store_result();
  $rows = $stmt->num_rows;
  
  if($rows > 0) {
   $stmt->bind_result($activacion);
   $stmt->fetch();
   
   if($activacion == 1){
    $msg = "La cuenta ya se activo anteriormente.";
    } else {
    if(activarUsuario($id)){
     $msg = 'Cuenta activada.';
     } else {
     $msg = 'Error al Activar Cuenta';
    }
   }
   } else {
   $msg = 'No existe el registro para activar.';
  }
  return $msg;
 }
 
 function activarUsuario($id)
 {
  global $mysqli;
  
  $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE usuarios SET activacion=1 WHERE id = ?");
  $stmt->bind_param('s', $id);
  $result = $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->close();
  return $result;
 }
```

```css
$registro = registraUsuario($usuario, $pass_hash, $nombre, $email, $activo, $token, $tipo_usuario);

    if ($registro > 0) {
     
     $url = 'http://'.$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].'/Cerberos/Formularios/login/activar.php?id='.$registro.'$val='.$token;

     $asunto = 'Activar Cuenta - Sistema Cerbero ';
     $cuerpo = "Estimado $nombre: <br /><br />Para Continuar con el proceso de registro, es indispensable de click en la siguiente direccion <a href='$url'>Activar Registro</a>";
     if (enviarEmail($email, $nombre, $asunto, $cuerpo))
      {
       echo "Para terminar el proceso de registro siga las instrucciones que le hemos enviado al correo electronico: $email";
       echo "<br><a href='index.php'>Iniciar Sesion</a>";
       exit;

      }else{
       $errors[] = "Error al Enviar el Correo"; 
      }

    }else
    {
     $errors[] = "Error al Registrar";
    }
```

```html
<?php

require 'funcs/conexion.php';
require 'funcs/funcs.php';

if (isset($_GET["id"]) AND isset($_GET['val'])) 
{
 $idUsuario = $_GET['id'];
 $token = $_GET['val'];

 $mensaje = validaIdToken($idUsuario, $token);
}



?>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Registro</title>
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" >
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" >
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>

 </head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">
   
   <h1><?php echo $mensaje; ?></h1>

   <br />
   <p><a class="btn brn-primary btn-lg" href= "index.php" role="button">Iniciar Sesi&oacute;n</a></p>

  </div>
  
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Probá declarar la variable `$msg` antes de la linea `if($rows > 0)` en la función `validaIdToken`. Si la ejeción no pasa por ese `if` la variable no se define.

Comment: igual me arroja el mismo error.

Comment: Por favor pulsa en [edit]  y pon exactamente el mensaje de error que arroja. No sé si te refieres a la variable `$msg`. Revisando el código, es imposible que arroje que `$msg` no existe. El código controla todos los flujos y debe crearse siempre esa variable. Pon el mensaje de error, indicando también en qué archivo ocurre y en qué línea de ese archivo.

Comment: Y, haz un `var_dump($_GET);` en el último archivo que muestras, pues si el error se refiere a esa variable `$mensaje` entonces es porque una de las dos claves que buscas en el GET (`id` o `val`) no existen.

Answer (score 0):

## El problema

En la imagen se puede apreciar que en la barra de navegación estás enviando `id=2&$val=5fb....`

Al enviar los datos en la URL lo que se hace es meterlos en un array (la super global `$_GET`) que, en tu caso, sería así:

```
$_GET= array (
                'id'=>2,
                '$val'=>'5fb....'
             );
```

En ese caso, tu código no cumple esta condición:

```
if (isset($_GET["id"]) AND isset($_GET['val'])) 
{
    $idUsuario = $_GET['id'];
    $token = $_GET['val'];

    $mensaje = validaIdToken($idUsuario, $token);
}
```

Porque en `$_GET` no existe la clave `val`, se te escapó un `$` en alguna parte y la clave se llama `$val`.

## Solución chapuza

Buscar la clave como `$val` en cuyo caso, como dato curioso, **tendrás que usar comillas simples sí o sí, porque si usas comillas dobles, PHP interpreta que estás buscando una variable llamada `$val` y, aunque te devuelva el valor, te dará un `Undefined variable: val`

```
if (isset($_GET["id"]) AND isset($_GET['val'])) 
{
    $idUsuario = $_GET['id'];
    $token = $_GET['$val']; #Chapuza

    $mensaje = validaIdToken($idUsuario, $token);
} else {
    $mensaje = "Faltan datos";

}
```

## Solución óptima

Corregir el origen de los datos, haciendo que te mande la URL así: `id=2&val=5fb....`

Y recuperar como lo estabas haciendo, pero siempre poniendo un `else` por si no lo encuentra:

```
if (isset($_GET['id']) AND isset($_GET['$val'])) 
{
    $idUsuario = $_GET['id'];
    $token = $_GET['val']; #No chapuza :-)

    $mensaje = validaIdToken($idUsuario, $token);
} else {
    $mensaje = "Faltan datos";
}
```

Comment: el unico parametro donde estoy colocando esa variable es aca $url = 'http://'.$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].'/Cerberos/Formularios/login/activar.php?id='.$registro.'$val='.$token;

Comment: Claro, ponlo así: `$url = "http://$_SERVER[SERVER_NAME]/Cerberos/Formularios/login/activar.php?id=$registro&val=$token";`  he evitado concatenaciones confusas. Si observas, precisamente es ahí donde se te estaba escapando una  `$` antes de `val`.